# Can not keep Responsive layot

Tags: responsive-design

I m working on a site and here it is http://mytownsville.info/Young-Passion/ 
The problem is i can not keep the responsive layout. The Logo is just messed up when i narrow the browser. Loooking for your help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're using position:absolute; which can make things overly complicated for responsive design. Have you looked into flex box?:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/

Or you can also use "float" with percentage widths. This will allow your content to scale down but still keep the same layout (without being pushed to different lines, etc.). Then when you get to really small widths you can use CSS3 media queries to snap to a different layout.

In general it's recommended to start with the mobile/smallest layout first and then build up, rather than the other way around.